# "Show Inspector" not showing in ios simulator and "The Map Size Property Not Writable" issue in android react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am getting weird problem while running react-native application.

In IOS I am not able to see Inspector, when i click on the show inspector it changes to hide inspector but the inspector is not shown.

In ANDROID also when i run the app the app loads properly, but when i try to navigate to any other class or screen it gives me following error:

**The map size property is not writable.
PLEASE FIX ME: You are changing the map size property which should not be writable and will break in production.**

I am using Visual Studio Code for development.

Tried searching a lot from last few days not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue. Check if you have turned Developer mode off.

I had turned off developer mode and forgot to turn it on again. Couldn't open inspector in Xcode simulator and my app throwing the same error in android simulator.

Switching on developer mode fixed it for me.

Check for this statement and comment it in case you want to switch off developer mode.

```
global.__DEV__ = false
```

Comment: can you please let me know how to do it ? I dont know how to do it. Any code command will be of help